# Laravel Cache:: Best Practices

Tags: php, caching, laravel

PHP Colleagues:

This question relates to best practices for using Laravel Cache.

The central objective is to reduce the number of accesses to the database for all the usual
performance-related reasons.  The application is a read-intensive news site with perhaps a dozen controllers at most, mostly resource-type.

Are there any documented best practices for the application design?  It seems obvious to me 
that since Cache:: is a one-line statement, it's easy to drop this into the controllers -- 
either return the cached data or call the model and cache the results. And invalidate the 
cache (maybe with an eager reload) when requests update the model. But is that a good practice?

Here's a first look at doing this in the controller

```
/**
 * Retrieve listing of the gallery resource.
 *
 * @uses GET /gallery to return all image_collections.
 *
 * @param int $id The gallery id
 *
 * @return Response - Contains a HTTP code and a list of articles.
 */
public function index()
{
    $response_data = array();
    $response_code = 200;

    // TRY TO RETURN A CACHED RESPONSE
    $cache_key = "gallery_index";
    $response_data = Cache::get($cache_key, null);

    // IF NO CACHED RESPONSE, QUERY THE DATABASE
    if (!$response_data) {
        try {
            $response_data['items'] = $this->gallery->all();
            Cache::put($cache_key, $response_data, Config::get('app.gallery_cache_minutes'));
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $response_code = 500;
            $response_data['error'] = ErrorReporter::raiseError($ex->getCode());
        }
    }

    return Response::json($response_data, $response_code);
}
```

I've heard the suggestion that you could use Laravel Route Filters to cache the responses, 
but I can't quite get my head around the idea.

Thoughts?  References?  Examples?

Thanks to all,
Ray

Comment: Cache management is hard, it all depends on what you're caching.  If you're presenting an approximated value you may not care if the underlying data is somewhat out of date, conversely if you're caching something like ALCs it may always need to be correct (and then flushed when the underlying data store gets updated).

Comment: You should decouple your logic in your controller, for instance you could pass type-hint cache to your controller constructor, I also suggest that you create repositories for your caching, so you could leverage laravel caching abilities.

Answer (score 32):

Many people do this differently but when best practices are a concern I believe the best place to do caching is in your repository.

Your controller shouldn't know too much about the data source I mean whether it's coming from the cache or coming from the database.

Caching in the controller doesn't support the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) approach, because you find yourself duplicating your code in several controllers and methods thereby making scripts difficult to maintain.

So for me, this is how I roll in Laravel 5 not so different if are using laravel 4:

**1. Create GalleryEloquentRepository.php in App/Repositories**

```
namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Models\Gallery;
use Cache;
    
/**
 * Class GalleryEloquentRepository
 * 
 * @package App\Repositories
 */
class GalleryEloquentRepository implements GalleryRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Fetch all the galleries
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
     */
    public function all()
    {
        return Cache::remember('gallerys', $minutes='60', function()
        {
            return Gallery::all();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a gallery
     * 
     * @return \App\Models\Gallery
     */
    public function find($id)
    {
        return Cache::remember("gallerys.{$id}", $minutes='60', function() use($id)
        {
            return Gallery::find($id);
        });
    }
}
```

**2. Create GalleryRepositoryInterface.php in App/Repositories**

```
namespace App\Repositories;
    
/**
 * Interface GalleryRepositoryInterface
 * 
 * @package App\Repositories
 */
interface GalleryRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find($id);

    public function all();
}
```

**3. Create RepositoryServiceProvider.php in App/Providers**

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class RepositoryServiceProvider
 * 
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    //protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Repositories\GalleryRepositoryInterface',
            'App\Repositories\GalleryEloquentRepository'
        );
    }
}
```

**4. At the controller, you can do this**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use View;
use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Repositories\GalleryRepositoryInterface;

class GalleryController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(GalleryRepositoryInterface $galleryInterface)
    {
        $this->galleryInterface = $galleryInterface;

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $gallery = $this->galleryInterface->all();

        return $gallery ? Response::json($gallery->toArray()) : Response::json($gallery,500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, @Digilimit.

Comment: So, not in the models?

Comment: Model is also a good place but let's not over crowd model with lots of code.

Comment: I used Laracogs as a scaffolding tool. It generates structures like: controller -> service -> repository -> model.
My concern is: where to put my code: validation, cache...? Service or Repository? Why not controller? (sorry, I just try to get familiar with design pattern, and except MVC, I doesn't get it practically although I can understand its theory :( ). Thank you.

Comment: Nice approach! Just one small thing... If you use `Cache::remember()` I don't think you need to check if the key exists or not with `Cache::has()`. The `remember()` handles it.

Comment: Just adding a note here that `Cache::remember` now works in seconds rather than minutes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#cache-ttl-in-seconds

Comment: @EmekaMbah, Many thanks to you for your invaluable and educative post. Kindly note that a call to has() method is incorrect in this context return Cache:has('gallerys')->find($id); Please replace it with a call to get() method.

Comment: @EmekaMbah, May I point out that find($id) method is caching data that has already been catched by all() method and running a new query to fetch it from database if not found in cache. May I propose that you search for the record in the gallerys cache (cache created in all() method) first before running a new query to search database.