# Laravel caching - too much caching, what is good practice?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'd like to know if this is a good practice.

I have documents -> those documents have a document type -> that document type has some tabs and properties -> those properties have a data type and a value. So I have 7 tables that I need to query to gain all data needed. Also having some other queries here and there. On one page I had 11 queries. I think way too many.

Is it a good practice to cache each document (there can be 1000s of documents)?

```
 return Cache::rememberForever('documents_'.$id, function() use ($id) {
        return $this->document->where('document_id', $id)
            ->with(array('documentType.properties', 'values', 'documentType.tabs'))
            ->first();
    });
```

And on saving that document I'm clearing cache of that specific document.
This works fine and save a lot of queries, but is it bad to have such a large cache and why?

Comment: Cache everything you can

Comment: My only suggestion is while you do your development you could disable caching, but before releasing production activate for final test and release it.

Comment: @Steve awesome, so no down side? It's time to speed things up even more ^^

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I like that idea, is there a generic way in laravel to disable all caching?

Comment: No obvious downside no. You could do better though - anywhere where the entire page can be cached, you would get better performance caching at the webserver level, so php is never even called. However thats extra work that could easily be considered premature optimization if your site is currently fast enough

Comment: @TimvanUum To disable caching, use the `array` cache driver.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks! worked like a charm

Comment: For anyone who come across this question, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29508459) useful.